# Could not format sql correctly in pymysql

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

What I want is execute the sql 
`select * from articles where author like "%steven%"`.

For the sake of safety, i used like this way :

`cursor.execute('select * from articles where %s like %s', ('author', '%steven%')`

Then the result is just empty, not get a syntax error, but just empty set.
But I am pretty sure there is some thing inside, I can get result use the first sql. Is there anything run with my code ?

Comment: Try adding `print cursor._last_executed`, see what query is actually being executed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set a column name like a parameter where you're doing `where %s like %s`.  To dynamically set the column name you need to do actual string manipulation like:

```
sql = 'select * from articles where '+ sql_identifier('author') +' like %s'
cursor.execute(sql, ('%steven%',))
```

Where `sql_identifier` is your lib's function for making an identifier safe for SQL injection.  Something like:

```
# don't actually use this!
def sql_identifier(s):
  return '"%s"' % s.replace('"','')
```

But with actual testing and knowledge of the DB engine you're using.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is fact a minor mistake. Thanks to @Asad Saeeduddin, when I try to use `print cursor._last_executed` to check what has happened. I found that what is in fact executed is 
`SELECT * FROM articles WHERE 'title' LIKE '%steven%'`, look the quotation mark around the title, that's the reason why I got empty set.
So always remember **the string after formatting will have a quotation around**